# MySQL not using index instead using where

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mysql for my db. I have 200,000 records with 30 columns. I am creating a composite index using 6 columns(txn_date,v_name,transaction_status, sid, pnum, txn_num)  . When I do a explain on the following query having those 6 columns in where clause, the explain is using index till certain txn_date  and then its using the where condition based on output of explain command

```
SELECT * FROM transactions  
WHERE txn_date between '2021-01-10' and  '2021-01-19'
  and v_name ='Vo' 
  AND transaction_status = 'failed' 
  AND sid = '566' 
  AND txn_num = 100 
  AND p_num = 5;
```

In the above query when the txn_date  is date from 10 Jan to 18 Jan, its using index and above that its using where condition. Please help me out to use the index effectively so it uses index always

Comment: Sometimes composite index is not the solution. Because the index becomes so large that is cheaper to make a scan on the original table than looking at the index and then retrieve the records from the table. Try to create a index with only `txn_date` instead.

Comment: In addition to the above, sometimes MySQL won't bother using an index if a given table have only a few hundred/thousand records.  How large is this table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : it has 295,000 rows.

Comment: OK, and roughly how many records do you expect your query to actually return?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Now till 27,000 rows, its using index. Above that its using where condition

Comment: Another point to consider here is that if MySQL really thinks it has to return 10% of all records, it also might choose to not use the index.  Actually, I would expect it to be used here though.  Try the first suggestion by @lmarqs and see if that helps.

Comment: *Please help me out to use the index effectively so it uses index always* This makes no sense. For undex usage to be effective its selectivity must be over ~15-20. When the range is wide server decides that table scan is more efective (and it is probably that server is correct - try to force index usage!). If you need in effective index than create index which includes all other 5 columns listed in WHERE in any order (all of them are filtered by single value) then add `txn_date` as the most last column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Creating the index only with txn_data didn't help. Still the same result.

Comment: @Akina: In mysql the left most indexed column will be used in search I guess. So it doesn't make sense to put txn_date at the end of index

Comment: o_O Your guess claims that non-covering composite indices makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Akina I am not getting your statement. Can it be more clear?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0cbe37406a0eaf99f06b9b6a5377274

Comment: @Akina: makes sense. But there are situations where I want to query only with transaction_date such as txn_date >= '2020-11-01' and  txn_date <= '2020-11-30'

Comment: @Akina: Basicallly, if I have an index with transaction_date and my query is as such SELECT * FROM transactions  
WHERE txn_date between '2021-01-10' and  '2021-01-19'. Then till 2021-01-09, its using index. After that its using where clause

Comment: As I have said *server decides that table scan is more efective .. try to force index usage*, then compare execution times with and without index usage.

Comment: @Akina: After forcing to use index, the query time is 0.00415 ms whereas without index usage was around 0.00636

Comment: @akina in the fiddle db, the db dataype is date and not datetime. any specific reason of you using the datetime?

Comment: MySQL has to decide on statistics. The point where using an index will be slower than not using it *is* somewhere - just increase the date range to e.g. the whole table and test with and without forcing the index. and then lower it to find the exact point. MySQL does not know the exact point a priori, so it uses a guess that works on average. That guess is based on theory, experience, practice and tests that the mysql developers did. If you know/tested that for your specific case, the guess is wrong/the index is always better (and there is no better way to do it): that is what *force* is for.

Comment: @lmarqs - your Comment is only partially right; see my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

End with the date; start with columns tested with '='.

The columns of an index will be used from the left, but won't be used past the range test, so your index was no better than a 1-column index with just the date.  Given that, the Optimizer probably saw that more than about 20% of the table would need to be used (based on the date range), and punted.  That is, it decided that it would probably be faster to simply scan the table.

This discussion applies to any size of table.

`FORCE INDEX` will force it to use the index, but so what?  The Optimizer is pretty good at deciding that a small date range can effectively use the index, but a large range cannot.  If you add a `FORCE`, it may help some of the time but hurt badly in other cases.

By having all the `=` tests *first* in the index, obviates much of the discussion about how many days are in the date range.

More on index building:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: The 31 days max will be queried. Is it ok to use force_index on some specific queries?

Comment: @user846445 - Experiment.  Time it with `FORCE INDEX` and with `IGNORE INDEX` and with no hint.  If not using the index is faster, why worry that it is not using the index?

Comment: sure will do it